# Why ip redirect to subdomain?

Tags: apache, centos, ip, virtualhost, powerdns

I have a VPS, which has its own IP. Having installed Apache, when I put the IP address into Chrome, it redirects to Apache index. I installed some subdomains with virtualhost and PowerDNS (using poweradmin), but now, when I put the ip on chrome, it redirects to WordPress subdomain! (WordPress is the first virtualhost in the file .conf). I don't know why it happens, and I've not found any solution.

Comment: Consider to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/), if English is not your native language.

Comment: One ip, one site, as simple as that, and that will be either the first loaded or the one marked as `_default_`. If you use the DNS name it should work. Otherwise, post a sample of `apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS` and ip config.